# Free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

This is problem 4.15 in Chapter VI of the book Algebra: Chapter 0.

> View $\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$, where $x$ and $y$ act by $0$. Find the free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $R$.

What I did is as the following:

Since $\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(x,y)$, and $(x,y)$ is a regular sequence of $R$, then we can use Koszul complex to have the following exact sequence:

$$0\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}R\stackrel{d_2}{\longrightarrow}R\oplus R\stackrel{d_1}{\longrightarrow}R\stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow}\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x,y]}{(x,y)}\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}0$$

where $d_1((m,n))=mx+ny$, $d_2(m)=(ym,-xm)$.

Is this a correct way to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is.${}$

Comment: Btw I don't know how Aluffi handled this topic but "find the free resolution" is a bit weird, it should rather be "find a free resolution".